# Advice on setting shell's character set

Tags: shell, character-encoding

`M-x shell` has been my friend for decades, and I've always been comfortable even sympathetic with his insistence on being a dumb terminal (i.e. `TERM=dumb`).  But recently I've found my self setting `LC_ALL` by hand so that python won't default to ASCII on its standard streams.  I vaguely recall having similar problems at other times with ruby and perl.

So, my question: What is a good approach to setting things up so I don't have to set `LC_ALL` by hand?  For example, should I just slam this in `shell-mode-hook`?

Answer (score 1):

Would setting [TERM=emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7130073/how-do-i-tell-a-shell-that-it-is-running-from-within-emacs) as part of the actual shell startup help? I have had

```
  [ "${INSIDE_EMACS}" != "" ] && export TERM=emacs
```

in my ~/.bashrc for longer than I can remember and `(shell)` has been part of my startup sequence for decades.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I have been doing to address this.

```
(defun force-lc-all-for-shell ()
  "For the benefit of python we force LC_ALL to utf-8."
  (comint-send-string (get-buffer-process (current-buffer)) "LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\n"))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook 'force-lc-all-for-shell)
```

But it seems quite ad hoc, and obviously doesn't affect other ways of running programs from Emacs.