# Where is this cruft coming from in shell-mode and term-mode?

Tags: shell, term

```
tcsh$ cd ~
^[]0;sallred@calamity:/home/sallred^G
tcsh$ cd bin
^[]0;sallred@calamity:/home/sallred/bin^G
tcsh$
```

What is this cruft that is appearing before my prompt (or perhaps more appropriately, *after* my command) and how can I remove it?

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but are you setting `prompt` in your .cshrc (or equivalent) file?

Comment: @glucas `set prompt "\ntcsh$ "` This stuff only appears from within emacs.  Additionally, there is nothing in my rc file that matches this general pattern: `.*:.*@.*`.

Comment: Just a guess: Is your shell trying to set the `xterm` window title?

Comment: @Constantine That's exactly what it's doing.  I've removed the problem statement for now (`alias precmd 'echo -n "\033]0;${USER}@${HOST}:${PWD}\007"'`), but is there any way to get Emacs to ignore or override this?

Comment: I'm tempted to make a new question along the lines of "use a different shell rc file for emacs" and dupe this to that; it seems like the general case might be more useful for search engines.

Comment: When writing [this answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5313/2355) I discovered `comint-preoutput-filter-functions`. See `C-h v comint-preoutput-filter-functions`. You should be able to write a filter that removes the cruft before it gets inserted into a `shell-mode` buffer. `term-mode` is not based on `comint`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2600/advice-on-setting-shells-character-set/). Basically you need to avoid creating aliases for commands or prompts that assume that every shell is running where there is a window title to be set. Or create functions that do things differently depending on what kind of terminal they find themselves in.

As part of my bash initialization I do something like:

```
case "$TERM" in
    (emacs)
        # Emacs shell differences ...
        ;;
    (xterm*|dtterm*|linux|screen)
        # Embed working directory in window title
        PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${SSH_TTY:+${HOSTNAME%%.*}:}${PWD##*/}\007"'
        ;;
    *)
        # Unrecognized terminal types get nothing
        ;;
esac
```

You need tcsh's precmd to do something equivalent.