# Shell-mode conditional execution

Tags: shell-mode

After a command terminates in `shell-mode`, I want to execute an additional command conditional on `stdout`. How can this be automated?

Comment: Could you give a minimal example of output and command?

Answer (score 1):

Add a hook to `comint-output-filter-functions`. In the example below, `ls` is sent to the shell if the output from a command matches `"foo"`.

```
(defun my-hook (str)
  (when (string-match "foo" str)
    (insert "ls")
    (comint-send-input)))

(add-hook 'shell-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (make-local-variable 'comint-output-filter-functions)
            (add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions #'my-hook)))
```